# Is there a tag to get the parents url like {{entry.url}}?

Tags: templating, url

Is there a tag that can shorten the following:

```
{% set parentPage = entry.getParent() %}
{% if parentPage %} <a href="{{ parentPage.url }}">{{ parentPage.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Something like `{entry.getParentUrl}`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shortest way, still checking if the parent exists, is to use (not tested):

```
{{ entry.parent ? entry.parent.link }}
```

[`entry.link`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#link), or `entry.getLink()` gives you the `<a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>` part.

Comment: wonderful > {{ entry.parent.url }} was all i'm looking for